# The message received from the server could not be parsed

Tags: asp.net, ajax

I am getting following error in asp.net webpage

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException:
>   The message received from the server
>   could not be parsed. Common causes for
>   this error are when the response is
>   modified by calls to Response.Write(),
>   response filters, HttpModules, or
>   server trace is enabled.

The scenario of my page is as following

1. I have asp.net page that is implementing Ajax
2. User Control all code is inside update panel
3. Model popup extender at aspx page for User Control.

When I click a button on the aspx page a popup appears, but further when I click button at user control responsible for population of grid / click on the radio button to fill the dropdown list in both case the above-mentioned error appears.

Answer (score 30):

Add PostBackTrigger in UpdatePanel with the ControlID

```
</ContentTemplate>
<Triggers>
    <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="PostbackButtonName" />
</Triggers>
```

Answer (score 14):

Had to register the button for post back with the ScriptManager:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this).RegisterPostBackControl(btnExport);            
}
```

Answer (score 2):

After being stumped for a while, I finally realized that I had been setting the "runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests" value to "true" in my web.config, and had subsequently removed the Module but not this setting.

By switching my web.config setting to:

```
<system.webServer>
  <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false"/></system.webServer>
```

Done Deal...! :)

Comment: This was it for me as well.

Answer (score 1):

- If use in Repeater:  event rpt_ItemDataBound add:

  ImageButton btnDownload = (ImageButton)e.Item.FindControl("btnDownload ");

  ```
             if (btnDownload != null)
             {   ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page).RegisterPostBackControl(btnDownload);
                 var scriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
                 if (scriptManager != null)
                   scriptManager.RegisterPostBackControl(btnDownload);
             }
  ```

Comment: - It not inside control other add in updatepanel
    
`<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="upl">
    <ContentTemplate>
    </ContentTemplate>
   <Triggers>
           <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnDownload" />
   </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>`

Answer (score 1):

I got this error message when I put an UpdatePanel inside of another UpdatePanel.